# Set exclude on collection in multiple viewlayers

Tags: python, rendering, collections, viewlayers

I'm trying save the values of the `exclude` property from all the collections in every viewlayer(I have multiple viewlayers).

I'm trying to save my current state, so I can re-apply later. I'm saving it in a list written to a .Json files with this format [viewlayerName, collectionnName, exclude] the data types are string, string, bool.

I have a hard time finding a way to set the property back. Does anyone have an idea how I can set the exclude value based on the view_layer and the collection_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exclude` property is part of the [LayerCollection](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html) in `ViewLayer`, not the `Collection` itself. Basically some extra information that `ViewLayer` wraps around collections which is unique to that view layer. That is to say a collection can be excluded in one view layer and included in another.

Here's how you can search for a collection by name and apply the `exclude` setting:

```py
import bpy

# Helper to list all LayerCollections in the view layer recursively
def all_layer_collections(view_layer):
    stack = [view_layer.layer_collection]
    while stack:
        lc = stack.pop()
        yield lc
        stack.extend(lc.children)
        

def set_collection_excluded(scene, view_layer_name, collection_name, exclude):
    view_layer = scene.view_layers.get(view_layer_name, None)
    if view_layer:
        for lc in all_layer_collections(view_layer):
            if lc.collection.name == collection_name:
                lc.exclude = exclude
    

set_collection_excluded(bpy.context.scene, "ViewLayer_001", "Collection 2", False)
```

Comment: Super, it works thanks for the explanation!